# Combine SUB_DATE AND TIMEDIFF to substract 1 hour in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I'm having problems with `timediff` and `DATE_SUB`. Here is my MYSQL query:

```
SELECT id, clock_user_id, clock_date,

(Select clock_time from aura_clock where aura_clock.clock_type = 'Start' and  
 aura_clock.clock_date = t1.clock_date) as start, (Select clock_time 
 from aura_clock where aura_clock.clock_type = 'Stop' 
 and aura_clock.clock_date =   
 t1.clock_date) as Stop,
```

**THE PROBLEM START HERE**

```
TIMEDIFF((select clock_time FROM aura_clock t 
WHERE t.clock_date = t1.clock_date AND t.clock_time > t1.clock_time 
ORDER BY t.clock_time LIMIT 1), MIN(clock_time)) as spent

FROM aura_clock t1 WHERE t1.clock_date >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 
WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY),INTERVAL 15 day) 
AND t1.clock_date < DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) + 6 day)

GROUP BY clock_date
```

The result is :

[image]

Now, I want to subtract 1 hour from the time spent using `DATE_SUB` but it didn't work.

Comment: please provide som sample data and table structure in sqlfiddle.com

Comment: I'm not sure what is your problem here, If you want to get spent -1h just do `(spent - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AS new_spent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as **mirkobrankovic**  wrote:

```
((TIMEDIFF((select clock_time FROM aura_clock t 
WHERE t.clock_date = t1.clock_date AND t.clock_time > t1.clock_time 
ORDER BY t.clock_time LIMIT 1), MIN(clock_time))) - INTERVAL 1 HOUR) AS new_spent
```

should work

EDIT:

The best i got is time in seconds :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18160/66/0

a lot depends on MYSQL version

Comment: Should be `DATE_SUB( ..., INTERVAL 1 HOUR)` or `DATE_ADD( ..., INTERVAL -1 HOUR)`

Comment: try now, there could be problem with brackets

Comment: used my localhost and worked, but on production server didn't :/ Thats why i used `time_to_sec()` in reverse You can use `SEC_TO_TIME()`

Comment: Jaczes thank you for your response, this is very weird but still doesn't work, here is the sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18160/11.  I copied and paste from your response and I'm getting nulls.. Thanks my friend

Comment: It's all because CLOCK_TIME has strange value eg. `January, 01 1970 23:34:38+0000` at SQLFIDDLE. Please change it onto version 5.1.61... and see